# How to mount a Microsoft Windows 7 USB media under Linux?

Tags: windows-7, linux, usb, mount

I have an original Microsoft Windows 7 USB key. I would like to mount it under Linux, but all my attempts have failed :

```
# mount -o ro -t ntfs /dev/sdd1 /mnt/usb/
Failed to read last sector (16439295): Argument invalide
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
   or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
   or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
   or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
   or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdd1': Argument invalide
The device '/dev/sdd1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

I have tried with ntfs and vfat without success. How could I mount it please ?

Comment: What do you mean by `original Microsft Windows 7 USB key` ? Is it simply that it has been formatted by Windows ? By the way, are you sure it's a NTFS parition ? USB keys are often formatted with FAT32 by Windows.

Comment: What does `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdd` say?

Comment: I mean the usb key is a Microsoft manufactured one. This information may be important as they might have introduced some special features, I don't know.
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdd
Disk /dev/sdd : 8019 Mo, 8019509248 bytes, 15663104 sectors
Units = sector of 1 × 512 = 512 bytes
Secteur size (logic / physic) : 512 bytes / 512 bytes
size of I/O (minimal / optimal) : 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk Id : 0x00000000

Comment: But, have you tried mounting the key as a `FAT32` partition, or even without specifying the `-t ...` option to `mount` ?

Comment: I have FAT and VFAT in the kernel 2.6.37, but only vfat is known by mount. I have tryed vfat, ntfs, fat, fat32, with sdd and sdd1. # mount -o ro /dev/sdd  /mnt/usb leads to: bad file system, bad options, bad superblock on /dev/sdd, missing code page or auxilliary software, or other error.

Comment: `Disk Id : 0x00000000` ? Very interesting. According your `fdisk -l` output there no any partitions on your disk. That is why you can't mount. Try to reformat it.

Comment: fat32 and fat are unknown from my system. I have only vfat, msdos,  and ntfs. Nothing more in the kernel as far as I could see. If I mount without -t, I have the same error. If I boot on the key, it works, so the key is alright. Possibly fdisk does not recognise everything, especially if M$ does not want it to work.....

Comment: We are not going to wear the Earth for that. I could finaly order a reinstallation CD media from my computer provider : 15€.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ordered a reinstallation DVD. By error, they first sent me another USB key, which lead to the same result. Of course, with the DVD, everything is fine.